# Is AVAudioPlayerNode isPlaying flag set as soon as scheduleBuffer is called?

Tags: ios, avaudioengine

I've got two AVAudioPlayerNodes.

I schedule one using scheduleBuffer.

I want to cancel it before it starts but not if it has already started.

How do I know if it has actually started?

The isPlaying flag appears to be set as soon as it is scheduled rather than when it actually starts at the scheduled time.

Comment: Are you calling play() or play(at:) on the nodes?

Comment: I'm calling play() on the nodes.

Comment: Didi you get it figured out?

Comment: I need it now! Did you get it ?

Answer (score 0):

AVAudioPlayerNode takes a render cycle after calling `play()` before actual audio starts playing.  If you are trying to identify the time between `play()` and audio being played, you can get the playerNode's playerTime and look for negative (or less than specified with `play(at:)`) sampleTime values.  But since you're on different threads than the audio being scheduled, there's still a chance that a render cycle's worth of audio can squeeze out before you stop the player.

```
let playerTime = playerNode.playerTime(forNodeTime: AVAudioTime.init(hostTime: mach_absolute_time()))
print("sample time \(playerTime.sampleTime)")
```